# How to get array defined in a php file to a variable

Tags: php

I have a php file named config.php in which I defined the application settings in an array format like

```
<?php

return array(
 'user' => 'jaison',
 'email' => 'test@test.com',
);

?>
```

Inside the main app files I need to get the array to a variable, so that they can be used like this.

```
<?php 
 $settings = include 'config.php';
?>
```

I would like to know if there is there any alternative method to do like this instead of using include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course there are alternatives, but the way you are doing it is fine (this is how I'd do it) and I know at least of one [popular framework](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/core.php#L800) that also does this.

The advantage of this method is you don't have to define any variables inside your include file (which would be imported into the namespace and may be clutter) and the returned structure and can be assigned to whatever is required.

Answer (score 3):

you might want to use 'require' ?

other than that, its perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is another way without using include / include_once / require / require_once.

But you can use something like...

**config.php**

```
<?php
$settings = array(
 'user' => 'jaison',
 'email' => 'test@test.com',
);

?>
```

In main app use

```
<?php 
 include 'config.php';
 // Use $settings as if its defined above.
?>
```

Comment: yes ur right. but the config.php file structure is strict like return array(....);. and not able to change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use this setting inside all pages in your system. I think you can use constants.

Ex:

```
define("USER","jaison");
define("EMAIL","test@test.com");
```

So you can refer it anywhere once you included the config file.

Ex:

```
echo  USER;
```

Comment: The OP doesn't provide enough context, so constants are not necessarily the best way to go.